# Index over a specific dimension in Numpy and prevent indexing any other

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to write an object that allows indexing the first dimension of a numpy array and that should prevent the indexing of any other.

```
import numpy as np

class Foo:
    """
    Object that allows indexing the first dimension of arr
    """
    def __getitem__(self, my_slice):
        arr = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
        return arr[my_slice]

foo = Foo()

# Valid usages:
foo[0] # first row of arr
foo[:2] # two first rows of arr
foo[[0, 2]]  # rows 0 and 2 of arr

# Invalid usages that must raise an Exception but are currently not:
foo[0, 0]
foo[..., 0]
foo[np.newaxis]
foo[[0,2], [0]]
foo[[[0,2], [0]]]
foo[[0,2, np.newaxis]]
```

With the solution above (`arr[my_slide]`), the valid cases pass (good) but the invalid cases pass too (not good). What to put in `__getitem__` to satisfy all requirements?

Comment: "I am trying to write an object that allows indexing the first dimension of a numpy array and that should prevent the indexing of any other." - why do you want to do that? Do you care if they do something like `foo[:][:, 0]`?

Comment: I care because I am actually indexing several arrays. The first dimension of all these arrays has the same meaning so it makes sense to index them, but the other dimensions have different meanings. Indexing these other dimensions would create awful bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to just wrap the `my_slice` in a `tuple`. Given that it's the first (and only) element of the tuple it should be interpreted as the index for the first dimension:

```
import numpy as np

class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, my_slice):
        arr = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
        return arr[tuple([my_slice])]  # or "return arr[my_slice, ]"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well with the initial question. However I've discovered more nasty cases (indexing with a list); cf. my updated question. Any suggestion?

Comment: @NicolasBedou I updated the answer. The `foo[0, 0]` case still works but different than usual (it just indexes the first dimension two times) :)

Comment: Thanks, however it seems to me that the ``foo[0, 0]`` is not acceptable but way too surprising.

Comment: @NicolasBedou Well, what you're attempting here is surprising anyway, what's the problem with an additional surprise? Note that you could use a combination of my first answer and the edited one. That should give you an idea how to catch these cases. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better solution that the one in the original post:

```
class Foo:
    """
    Object that allows indexing the first dimension of arr
    """
    def __getitem__(self, my_slice):
        arr = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))

        if np.empty(arr.shape[0])[my_slice].ndim > 1:
            raise IndexError
        return arr[my_slice]
```

With this, `foo[0, 0]` and `foo[np.newaxis]` raise as desired an IndexError but some cases like `foo[..., 0]` are not properly handled.
So the question is still open.